# Need some help in understanding this circuit

Tags: operational-amplifier, sensor, circuit-analysis

[image]

This circuit is taken from this website.
http://www.circuit-finder.com/categories/sensor/temperature-sensor/905/temperature-controlled-switch

What is the purpose of R2 and R3 in this circuit?

I use voltage divider rule to calculate R2 which is R2/(R2+P1+R1) * 5V = 4.6987V
Converting it to degree Celsius , it is 46.987 degree Celsius.

Does it mean that the range is from 0 ~ 46.987 degree Celsius? Only when the sensor voltage rises above the ref voltage level for P1 (which is around 0.06 V = 30 degree Celsius since P1 is set to 10k ohm) , the output of the comparator toggles to the full supply voltage level

The purpose of R3 is it to limit current flow?

Answer (score 2):

Note that the temperature signal from the LM35 is compared to the output of the voltage divider formed by R2, P1, and R1.  You could have asked similarly what the point of R1 is.

In theory, you could connect the ends of P1 to power and ground directly.  It could still be adjusted to the desired temperature.  However, the adjustment would be more coarse.  Both R1 and R2 limit the adjustment range, which gives you finer control over the range you do get.

R3 together with R4 controls the amount of positive feedback, or *hysteresis* in this case.  The bigger R3 is relative to R4, the larger the hysteresis "dead zone".

The purpose of hysteresis is to crisply switch the output on or off, not have it being partially driven when the temperature is near the threshold.  Put another way, hysteresis provides the "snap action" so that the load is always driven full on or full off.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding R2: You're using the formula to calculate the voltage across R2 !?!?
More sense makes: (R1 + P1)/(R1+P1+R2) * 5V = 300 mV
And and the lowest side of P1: 180 mV
So that would make the range 180 - 300 Kelvin or - 93 to 27 degrees celcius.

R3 works in combination with R4 introducing a little bit of **positive feedback**, this adds some hysteresis to make the opamp switch more abruptly. This results in that for example the **on** voltage would become 41 mV while the **off** voltage is 39 mV. Without hysteresis the trip voltage could be 40 mV with the chance that the circuit quickly starts switching on and off around 40 degrees. You want to avoid that !

Comment: How did you get 60mV ? (R1 + P1)/(R1+P1+R2) * 5V = 30mV ? so the range is from 0 to 30? I am still not sure what does R2 do?

Comment: That was a whoopsie ! It must be 300 mV (forgot to multiply by 5V) I updated the answer. The numbers are in the schematic also.

Comment: What would happen if you remove R2 ? Then the "top" of P1 would be at 5 V so that would correspond to a switching temperature of 5000 K or 4727 degrees Celcius !!! Then most of the range of P1 would be useless. It would then be VERY difficult to set a switching temperature of 20 degrees for example. R2 makes the voltage at the top of P1 much lower so that it is in a practical range.

Answer (score 1):

Pad Pad Pad Brute force verify. :)

[image]